# Current time on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table. One of the columns, say column `Time_NOW` is of type `TIME`. if `Time_NOW` is null, i need that column entry be the current-time-- whenever that entry is looked up.

I tried the entry `now()` in column `Time_NOW` for the null values. However, it is setting its value for good to the current-time at the time of insertion to that row. 
what i need is the current-time at the time of reading that value from that row.

How can this be done?

I'm using MySQL.

TIA

Comment: thx for all the answers. looking to get JDBC on its feet to see what/how!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Current_time
```

Instead of

```
Now()
```

Like this

```
Select coalesce(time_now,current_time) as time_now
From your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to modify the definition of the column `Time_NOW` to get the behavior you described. To have a SQL query perform the specified operation (as I understand it), you would actually need to modify the query.

Your table definition remains as it is, with the column being nullable, e.g.

```
 `Time_NOW` TIME DEFAULT NULL
```

Your `SELECT` statement that "accesses" this column would need to retrieve the value from the column, test if that value is NULL, and either return the value of the column when it's *not* NULL, or return a *different* expression when the column is NULL.

Since the `Time_NOW` column is defined with a datatype of `TIME`, you'd almost certainly want the replacement value to be of the same datatype, so we want that alternate expression to return `TIME` (not `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`, etc.)

The expression `TIME(NOW())` will return the current time (HH:MM:SS), according to the server clock, and the timezone of the client.  (This isn't the only expression that will return the current time; there are other expressions that will return the same value.)

The conditional test (for `Time_NOW` being NULL or not) can be done is several different ways. As examples, using an ANSI-standard `CASE` expression, e.g.:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.Time_NOW IS NULL THEN TIME(NOW()) ELSE t.Time_NOW END AS Time_NOW 
  FROM mytable t
```

or, using a MySQL `IF()` function:

```
SELECT IF(t.Time_NOW IS NOT NULL,t.Time_NOW,TIME(NOW())) AS Time_NOW
```

or, using the `ISNULL()` function:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t.Time_NOW,TIME(NOW())) AS Time_NOW
```

or using the `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.Time_NOW,TIME(NOW())) AS Time_NOW
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT COALESCE(Time_NOW, now())`

Comment: OP says datatype of `Time_NOW` column is `TIME`. I recommend that the alternate value (to be returned when `Time_NOW` is NULL) be of the same datatype. Note that **`now()`** returns datatype other than `TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp):

```
Select COALESCE(Time_NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Here is the sample demo: [`SQL Fiddle`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/58a3f/5)

Comment: OP says datatype of `Time_NOW` column is `TIME`. I recommend that the alternate value (returned when `Time_NOW` is NULL) be of the same datatype, Note that **`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** returns a datatype other than `TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 create table test (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: OP wants column named `Time_NOW`, datatype of column is `TIME`, OP wants current server time value (HH:MM:SS) returned when the column value is NULL.